# Python functions only returning <function ... at .... >, what is the error?

Tags: python

I recently have been making a web app using Flask, and this file here is my current python file that connects to an API and makes some calls to it. Everything was working and running perfectly fine for days, when out of nowhere it stopped working, and now it only returns `<function (name of the function) at (memory address)>`

Example output:

```
<function sportsOdds.getFootballOdds at 0x000001FCCC11D000>
```

I didn't even change any code in this so I have no idea why it decided to stop working. Please help! (REDACTED is simply my APIkey)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import json

import requests

from requests import Session

from pprint import pprint as pp

import string


class sportsOdds:

    def __init__(self):
        self.apiurl = 'https://api.the-odds-api.com'
        self.session = Session()

    def getSports(self):
        url = self.apiurl + '/v4/sports/?apiKey=REDACTED'
        r = self.session.get(url)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.json())

    def getFootballOdds(self):
        url = self.apiurl + '/v4/sports/americanfootball_nfl/odds/'
        params = {
            'api_key': 'REDACTED',
            'regions': 'us',
            'markets': 'spreads',
            'oddsFormat': 'american',
            'bookmakers': 'draftkings'
        }
        r = requests.get(url, params)
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

testObj = sportsOdds

pp(sportsOdds.getFootballOdds)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I would guess that this is because you aren't actually instantiating an instance of your class correctly, or even using the method for that matter.

The last two lines of code should be:

```py
testObj = sportsOdds()

pp(testObj.getFootballOdds())
```

So, now we call the instance methods on an instance and print the result of that instead of printing just the function definition.

Also, I would guess that you want to return stuff in your functions instead of just printing, but I'm going to assume that you are aware of this and that those prints are just for debugging